# Procedure dynamic MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Good morning everyone. I need a solution to minimize changes in procedures of inclusion and consultation and a table model for armanezar new fields.

with statement: insert, update and delete. (Procedure).

without using create.

For example: The base of people receive new courses every week. In the first week there was a need to include individuals, companies that worked, date of admission and dismissal.

In the second week, title and salary.

how shall I proceed with this without causing any impact on application?

I have 1 table and 1 procedure.

Comment: already thought about doing a temporary table and store in different tables, the question is more focused on just one table ... 
so far not managed to get the answer.